# How Can I Insert Data Into Database From A Form Properly?

Tags: php, forms, pdo

so I've been working on a form using an MVC approach that will insert data into a database using PDO. I have the addWine form, addWine controller, data access model and wine class model. On submission of the form nothing happens and the database isn't populated. Can someone pinpoint what I have done wrong here?

Wine Form

```
<form action= "" method="POST">
    <table>
     <b>Fill the form to add new wine</b><p><p>
    <tr>
    <td> Wine ID:     </td>
    <td><input type="text" name= "wineID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Country ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineCountryID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Size ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineSizeID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Rating ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineRatingID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Colour ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineColourID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Package ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="winePackageID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Category ID: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineCategoryID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Code: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineCode"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Price: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineCountryID"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Description: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineDescription"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Rating: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineRating"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Wine Image: </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="wineImage"/></td>
    </tr>

  </table><p><br>

  <center><input type="submit" name= "addWineButton" value="Add Wine"></center><p><p><p><p>
  </form>
```

Add Wine Controller

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
require_once('../Model/dataAccess.php');
require_once('../Model/wine.class.php');

$status = false;

if(isset($_POST["addWineButton"])){

$wineID = $_POST["wineID"];
$wineCountryID = $_POST["wineCountryID"];
$wineSizeID = $_POST["wineSizeID"];
$wineRatingID = $_POST["wineRatingID"];
$wineColourID = $_POST["wineColourID"];
$packageID = $_POST["packageID"];
$wineCategoryID = $_POST["wineCategoryID"];
$wineCode = $_POST["wineCode"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$wineRating = $_POST["wineRating"];
$wineIMG = $_POST["wineIMG"];

$wineAdd = new Wine();
$wineAdd->wineID = htmlentities($wineID);
$wineAdd->wineCountryID = htmlentities($wineCountryID);
$wineAdd->wineSizeID = htmlentities($wineSizeID);
$wineAdd->wineRatingID = htmlentities($wineRatingID);
$wineAdd->wineColourID = htmlentities($wineColourID);
$wineAdd->packageID = htmlentities($packageID);
$wineAdd->wineCategoryID = htmlentities($wineCategoryID);
$wineAdd->wineCode = htmlentities($wineCode);
$wineAdd->price = htmlentities($price);
$wineAdd->description = htmlentities($description);
$wineAdd->wineRating = htmlentities($wineRating);
$wineAdd->wineIMG = htmlentities($wineIMG);

addWine($wineAdd);
$status = "$description has been updated.";
 }
?>
```

Wine Class Model

```
<?php

class Wine {


var $wineID;
var $wineSizeID;
var $wineCountryID;
var $wineRatingID;
var $wineColourID;
var $wineCode;
var $price;
var $description;
var $wineRating;
var $wineIMG;
var $packageID;
var $wineCategoryID;

function __get($name){
return $this->$name;
}
function __set($name,$value){
$this->$name=$value;
 }
}
?>
```

Data Access Model

```
function addWine($wineAdd){
global $pdo;
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Wine
(wineID, wineCountryID, wineSizeID, wineRatingID, wineColourID, packageID,
wineCategoryID, wineCode, price, description, wineRating, wineIMG) VALUES  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
$statement->execute([$wineAdd->wineID,
                     $wineAdd->wineCountryID,
                     $wineAdd->wineSizeID,
                     $wineAdd->wineRatingID,
                     $wineAdd->wineColourID,
                     $wineAdd->packageID,
                     $wineAdd->wineCategoryID,
                     $wineAdd->wineCode,
                     $wineAdd->price,
                     $wineAdd->description,
                     $wineAdd->wineRating,
                     $wineAdd->wineIMG]);
  $statement->fetch();
  }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking for your form values in $_REQUEST instead of $_POST ?

Comment: @devlincarnate I was following an example. I had it originally as $_POST but that wasn't working either.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am fully willing to accept answers which will help me in solving issues.

Comment: On none of your other questions was there an acceptable answer?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure what you are referring to. This is my first question on this topic.

Comment: You have questions on other topics that you have not accepted answers for.

Comment: In the mean time, have you checked your error logs? You have a lot going on here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, I don't know how to check the error logs.

Comment: @JayBlanchard on the other topics, there is no option to accept answer that I see btw.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: You need to find out where your error logs are and how to read them (it's not hard). Without the ability to do this you will not be able to find and correct issues quickly.

Comment: @JayBlanchard okay, I've turned the error logs on but it's not reporting any errors.

Comment: You're not going to get HTML entities in a POST request, unless the user has taken the time to type them out, so no need to run `htmlentities()` on everything. Also you can't `fetch()` an `INSERT` result. I don't see anything glaringly obvious, but if "nothing happens" there should be an error somewhere.

Comment: @miken32 Oh okay thanks. I've removed fetch from the dataAcesss file and changed the $_REQUEST to $_POST but the results are the same. I really don't know what the issue here is.

Comment: Your form does not have an action specified so what are you expecting to be run when the submit button is pressed?

Comment: @Dave I've changed the action to addWine.php and nothing still. The form requires the addWineController file

Comment: Your form have no action to the controlee page

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile the controller automatically gets called, hence the require_once statement at the top of the page.....this statement isn't shown in the code above though

Comment: Make sure you include all these small things in your code because we gonna keep on sporting them as the actual fault,  and i dont see any updates on your code with the suggesions on the comment

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I've got it working now. Thanks

Comment: PDO does not throw exceptions by default, you have to configure it explicitly. The code you've shared doesn't reveal anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working now. I've updated the original post to reflect the changes. Thanks everyone for all the help.